# Bind event to multiple inputs that have same name

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In my ASP MVC page, we have a four or five different menus that are available depending on a user radio button group selection. Some of these fields share a text input box that I need to bind an even to. However, the event is only working in the first menu on the list. Is it possible to bind the same event to multiple inputs that share the same name?

**jQuery**

```
    $('#LastName').change(function () {
        if ($('#LastName').val() == '') {
            $('#BankName').html("");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetBankName", "Agent")',
                data: { routing: $('#RoutingNumber').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#BankName').val(data);
                    $('#BankName').text(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**ASP MVC**

This HTML is present on the page when it loads, however only one `fieldset` is visible at a time.

```
            <fieldset id="Enroll" style="width:380px; display: none;">
            .
            .
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)<span class="req">*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div> 
            <fieldset id="ModT" style="width:380px; display: none;">
            .
            .           
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)<span class="req">*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div> 
            <fieldset id="ModA" style="width:380px; display: none;">
            .
            .
                <div class="M-editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)<span class="req">*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="M-editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ids, but they are supposed to be unique.

That's why it is not working, because when doing `$('#LastName')`, jquery uses `document.getElementById` and it always returns a single element.

Use class instead. If you ABSOLUTELY need multiple ids (which is invalid HTML by the way), you can (but I do not recommend it) use `$('[id=LastName]')`

Comment: Great! You saved my day 7 years back:)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the jQuery selector?

```
$('input[name=your-input-name]')
```

instead of:

```
$('#LastName')
```

and also the binder, to cover the future inputs added:

```
$('input[name=your-input-name]').on("change", function () { });
```